# I have multiple row and multiple delete button i like delete single data in jsp

Tags: jsp

**retrive:**

```
<% while(rs.next()){  %>
   <div id="ch">
   Subject<%=i%>
       <input type="text" name="subn" value="<%=rs.getString(4)%>">
       <input type="text" name="subc" value="<%=rs.getString(3)%>"> 
       <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="de" 
                         onclick="jsp:form.action='DeleteJsp.jsp'">
    <br><br></div>
    <div id="ch1" >
        <input type="text" name="id'+i+'" value="<%=rs.getString(7)%>">
    </div>
  <% i++;
        }
    } %>
```

**for deletejsp page**

```
 d =request.getParameterValues("id");  
   if(d !=null) {  
      for(int i=0;i<d.length;i++){  
          coun=(String)d[i];  
          out.println(coun);  
      }  
   st.executeUpdate("delete  from AssignSubject where  ID="+coun+"");
   }
   System.out.println("Deleted success");
```

please see the code;

I retrieve multiple records with delete button. if click any delete button it will delete first row only. i have to delete  corresponding data  only. what can i do to achieve this in my program? please see the code and help me please. It will display 5 data with delete button.
i have to delete 5th data means, what can i do?
please give some ideas to improve my programing skills.

Comment: In each delete button create ID for it then while submitting the form pass the id also.Now in the delete.jsp retrieve the id and delete it

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to delete one record from db, you can send the record id by url. Like this

```
"DeleteJsp.jsp?id="your_table_id
```

So you can receive it in your deletejsp page like `d = request.getParameter("id");`. Hence you need not to iterate it. You can do like this,

```
if(d !=null) {  
    st.executeUpdate("delete from AssignSubject where  ID="+d+"");
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: how can i pass table id

Comment: Sorry its not the UI table id. It is the ID what you are getting from your `<%=rs.getString(7)%>`. That should be Unique ID of your `AssignSubject` table.